# private chat in xcode 7.3 using quickblox

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7, quickblox

I couldn't send message to an existing dialog. I have successfully logged in the quickblox and have created the instance to connect to the user. The session is automatically handled by the ios sdk(as written in the documentation) so I don't care about session handling. I am able to retrieve existing messages of the dialogs but unable to send messages to any dialog...Please help me. I found no way out of this!

my code is:

```
@IBAction func sendMessageButton(sender: UIButton) {

    QBChat.instance().addDelegate(self)

    let privateChatDialog = QBChatDialog(dialogID: self.dialogId, type: QBChatDialogType.Private)

    let message = QBChatMessage()
    message.text = self.sendMessageTextView.text
    let params : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    params["save_to_history"] = true
    message.customParameters = params
    privateChatDialog.sendMessage(message) { (error : NSError?) in
        print(error)
    }

}
```

the output is:

> [ChatService] Message SNT: @chat.quickblox.com">Rishi
>   message114673779285773aceda0eb4799f800000e
>   2016-07-01 18:28:48.238
>   Catchmates.temp_caseinsensitive_rename[7063:156246] [ChatService]
>   StreamManagement: did request acknowledgment nil 2016-07-01
>   18:28:49.161 Catchmates.temp_caseinsensitive_rename[7063:156246]
>   [ChatService] StreamManagement: did receive acknowledgments for stanza
>   ids count: 2